# To what degree is institutional affiliation a conflict of interest when submitting to a conference?

Tags: publications, conference, conflict-of-interest

I'm submitting to a conference, and in the part where you're supposed to indicate conflict of interest, they indicate that same affiliation is a conflict of interest.

So I've declared affiliation CoI for those program committee members with the same affiliation as me.

My question is: will this preclude them from reviewing my submission?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it will almost certainly preclude them from being involved in any way with handling your submission. That is the whole point of flagging someone as having a conflict of interest, so if they were not precluded you would not be asked to indicate those committee members.

Source: personal experience, including as recent program committee co-chair of a large conference.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you would be precluded in any way. More likely is that some committee members might have to recuse from any decisions if the conflict is deemed serious. Not all "same affiliation" relationships are conflicts, of course.

But it is a committee management issue, not a sorting one.

Comment: I think you’re answering a different question from what OP asked. It’s not about whether OP’s submission would be precluded from being reviewed, but about whether the people OP flagged would be precluded from being reviewers for the submission.

Comment: I flagged them specifically as being the same affiliation in the "conflict of interest" part of the submission (it was one of the drop-down options). It seems Buffy you're saying this might not preclude them from being a reviewer, while Dan is saying it definitely will?

Comment: @DanRomik, and OP, I interpreted "them" as the committee as a whole (i.e. the conference), not those specific individuals. As I said: "some committee members might have to recuse".

Comment: I'm curious about "Not all 'same affiliation' relationships are conflicts, of course", because my conference seems to think otherwise. Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: You have to list them, of course, but they may judge that, for example, having taught you one course in the past isn't sufficient reason to require recusal. Being your advisor is a different sort of situation, of course. You list - they judge. You list _potential conflicts_. They judge _actual conflicts_.